# SQLite and Java Cyrillic Incorrect Display

Tags: java, sqlite, encoding, cyrillic

I can't really get it right. I've created a database file with sqlite command interpreter and connected it to my Java program (JDBC driver is ok, included, working properly so far). By the way, working in NetBeans.

When i make a query like `SELECT * FROM DIRS;` and supposing to get some cyrillic names I get the following:

`0 «  C:\db\main\ 3`

`1   C:\db\salad\ 8`

`2 ¥á¥ C:\db\dessert\ 1`

Structue of table is id-DisplayName-Path-Size. So, displayname, that should be shown in Russian, prints out wrong.

If I create a database with Java, it runs ok.

How can I solve it? It's supposed to use with databases created before, so I wouldn't create my own in final project.

Comment: How is the data in the database encoded? UTF-8?

Comment: Probably, Windows shell is not rendering UTF-8 characters! Try `CHCP 65001` command before calling `sqlite3.exe`.

Comment: @LS_dev the output is in console of NetBeans or in Windows shell. In sqlite shell it ok. Let me check it with file output

Comment: What was supposed to be shown instead of `¥á¥`? `ТЅУЁТЅ`?

Comment: @LS_dev it's supposed to be shown 'ЖЖЖЖ'. I solved problem by using SQLite Database Browser, but it's not a proper one. 'pragma encoding' shows UTF-8 in both.